# Deserialize java.awt.Color -> java.io.InvalidClassException

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

i want to serialize and deserialize an Object, which contains a color array. (color[][])

The color array represents a small icon.

After some Builds i get an error when i try to deserialize the object:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: java.awt.Color; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 118526816875918197, local class serialVersionUID = 118526816881161077
```

What can i do to fix that?
The Object itself has the default UID (serialVersionUID = 1L;)...

Thank you :)

Comment: are you working with a server like jboss? maybe you have a conflict with the jars, a jar that you are using in local and ajar in the server..are differents...it hope it helps.

Comment: Heyho :) 
No, everything is local...
It worked some weeks ago with no problems... Don't know, why its crashing now :/ Can i set/see the UID of the color class?

Comment: are you working with maven?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on the error message again:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: java.awt.Color; 
local class incompatible: 
stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 118526816875918197, 
local class serialVersionUID = 118526816881161077
```

It seems that you serialized the class using one version of `Color` and try to deserialize it with other.

Here is the `serialVersionUID` in my environment.

```
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 118526816881161077L;
```

It matches your second `serialVersionUID`. However the first is different: `118526816875918197`. This fact is a little bit strange because I compared this version ID with java 6 and java 7 JDK and they are equal. I cannot compare it with older JDK as well as with JDK from other vendors (not from Oracle). So I can assume that you created your file with either older version of JDK or with JDK from other vendor (e.g. open JDK, IBM etc.) or in other platform.

If this is the case I suggest you to customize serialization of your class by implementing your own `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods. You do not have to re-implement serialization of all your classes. It is enough to wrap `Color` with your custom wrapper customize serialization for it.

BTW forward/backward compatibility of serialized object is a well known weakness of whole serialization mechanism of java. You can use alternatives, e.g. serialization to JSON, XML or other binary format.

For JSON you can use Jackson or Gson, for XML JAXB or Xstream, for binary format protobuff.

Comment: Thank you :)
The problem is: i am serialize and deserialize the file with my current build :O
I dont know, how the UID can change?

How can i wrap Color?